# Delphi / REST / JSON

Tags: json, rest, delphi

I'm using Delphi Tokyo 10.2 Update 1 and the RESTRequest, RESTResponse and RESTClient components to communicate with a REST server. This is my first attempt with REST/JSON.

I have successfully sent a login request (POST) and received the response expected (a GUID). I then use the GUID to do various other requests (GET). Two of the requests that are made send back an empty file and document JSON template which I then have to populate. This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure of the best way to update property values in the JSON object.

Here is the empty JSON file template I'm getting back:

```json
{
  "boxId": 0,
  "changedBy": 0,
  "customSort": "",
  "dateChanged": "1990-01-01T00:00:00",
  "dateStarted": "1990-01-01T00:00:00",
  "destruction": "1990-01-01T00:00:00",
  "documentCount": 0,
  "documents": {
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "Collection": [

    ]
  },
  "extraData": {
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "Collection": [

    ]
  },
  "fieldDefs": {
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "Collection": null
  },
  "field": [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "fileId": 0,
  "filePtr": 0,
  "id": 0,
  "isIndexed": false,
  "keyValue": "",
  "keyVisualValue": "",
  "labelPrinted": "1990-01-01T00:00:00",
  "lineItems": {
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "Collection": [

    ]
  },
  "notes": "",
  "objectType": 5,
  "projectId": 0,
  "routeInfo": null,
  "routingDoc": null,
  "remoteId": 0,
  "saveNotesOnly": false,
  "saveStyle": -999,
  "status": 1,
  "syncFlag": 0,
  "totalDocumentCount": 0,
  "viewerContext": 0
}
```

In Python to populate the first two values in the field property array I simply would do:

```py
inc_filetemplate = json.loads(requests.get(NEWFILE_string).text)
inc_doctemplate = json.loads(requests.get(NEWDOC_string).text)
filetemplate = inc_filetemplate
doctemplate = inc_doctemplate
filetemplate['field'][1] = dcn
filetemplate['field'][2] = batchname
```

EASY!!!! ;)

What is the best way to do this with Delphi?

I can get the values from the "field" array (first two items in this example which happen to be empty). Just not sure the best way to set the values for those items.

This is what I have started:

```delphi
procedure PopulateFileTemplate(const AFileTemplate: String);
var
  JO: TJSONObject;
  JOPair: TJSONPair;
  JOArray: TJSONArray;
  FieldDCN: String;
  FieldBatchName: String;

begin
  JO := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AFileTemplate) as TJSONObject;

  try
    if JO = nil then
    begin
      MessageDlg('Unable to parse JSON file template.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);

      Exit;
    end;

    JOArray := JO.Get('field').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    FieldDCN := JOArray.Items[0].Value;
    FieldBatchName := JOArray.Items[1].Value;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName);

    // Best way to set Values here???????

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName);
  finally
    JO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You need to choose a JSON library, such as Super Object.

Comment: Delphi also has its own [JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) built in to the RTL.

Comment: I have looked at and played with the JSON framework built in to the RTL. However, either I'm not doing something right or you can't set JSON property values as straight forward as you can with Python. I'll keep playing around with JsonTextReader and JsonTextWriter.

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: I have read the documentation, @DavidHeffernan. Parsing and retrieving values isn't the issue. Setting them is where I'm having issues. Not in the sense that it can't be done. I see the examples here. I'm just surprised Delphi doesn't have a better means to do it. Very ugly. As you see from the Python source code above, it's very simple. ;)

Thanks for responding.

Comment: Python is always simpler

Comment: BTW, I've read through many examples here given by @RemyLebeau. Very helpful.

Comment: @klbass68: What is the actual problem you are having with setting properties? Please update your question to show your actual code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: See above addition to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TJSONArray.Items[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray.Items) property returns a [`TJSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue), which in your example are [`TJSONString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString) objects since `fields` an array of strings.

[`TJSONArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray) is actually not designed to allow modifying *existing* objects in the array. You can add new objects to the end of the array, and remove arbitrary objects from the array, but you cannot insert new objects at arbitrary indexes, or replace existing objects with new objects.

The closest you can get to that kind of functionality is to construct a `TList<TJSONValue>` with the desired objects in it, and then pass it to `TJSONArray.SetElements()`.  Not ideal.

And `TJSONString` does not have any methods or properties for editing its `string` value (except for [`TJSONString.AddChar()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString.AddChar)).

You could try using an accessor/helper class to gain access to the protected [`TJSONString.FStrBuffer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString.FStrBuffer) member and then edit its content as needed:

```
type
  TJSONStringAccess = class(TJSONString)
  end;

procedure SetJSONStringValue(JSONValue: TJSONString; const S: string);
begin
  with TJSONStringAccess(JSONValue) do
  begin
    FStrBuffer.Clear;
    FStrBuffer.Append(S);
  end;
end;

procedure PopulateFileTemplate(const AFileTemplate: String);
var
  JO: TJSONObject;
  JOPair: TJSONPair;
  JOArray: TJSONArray;
  FieldDCN: TJSONString;
  FieldBatchName: TJSONString;
begin
  JO := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AFileTemplate) as TJSONObject;
  if JO = nil then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Unable to parse JSON file template.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    JOArray := JO.Get('field').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    FieldDCN := JOArray.Items[0] as TJSONString;
    FieldBatchName := JOArray.Items[1] as TJSONString;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN.Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName.Value);

    SetJSONStringValue(FieldDCN, '...');
    SetJSONStringValue(FieldBatchName, '...');

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN.Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName.Value);
  finally
    JO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
type
  TJSONStringHelper = helper class for TJSONString
    procedure SetValue(const S: string);
  end;

procedure TJSONStringHelper.SetValue(const S: string);
begin
  Self.FStrBuffer.Clear;
  Self.FStrBuffer.Append(S);
end;

procedure PopulateFileTemplate(const AFileTemplate: String);
var
  JO: TJSONObject;
  JOPair: TJSONPair;
  JOArray: TJSONArray;
  FieldDCN: TJSONString;
  FieldBatchName: TJSONString;
begin
  JO := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AFileTemplate) as TJSONObject;
  if JO = nil then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Unable to parse JSON file template.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    JOArray := JO.Get('field').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    FieldDCN := JOArray.Items[0] as TJSONString;
    FieldBatchName := JOArray.Items[1] as TJSONString;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN.Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The old value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName.Value);

    FieldDCN.SetValue('...');
    FieldBatchName.SetValue('...');

    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of DCN is: ' + FieldDCN.Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('The new value of BatchName is: ' + FieldBatchName.Value);
  finally
    JO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, consider switching to a 3rd party JSON library that natively supports editing values. Such as [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems like SuperObject may be the better alternative. In my research I did see people using it. Downloading now. Thanks again!